# Trouble using POST with core-ajax-dart to send JSON data to a server REST API

Tags: ajax, json, rest, dart, core-elements

I am having trouble sending JSON data to my custom REST sever using core-ajax-dart.  I can sucessfully send JSON data with the following

```
var host = window.location.hostname;
var data = JSON.encode(rows);
HttpRequest.request('http://$host:9999/services/directory/items/$instanceId', method: 'POST', mimeType: 'application/json', sendData: data).catchError((obj) {
  print(obj);
}).then((HttpRequest val) {
  print('response: ${val.responseText}');
}, onError: (e) => print("error"));
```

but when I try and do the same thing with core-ajax-dart,

```
<core-ajax-dart id="ajax"
  response="{{ response }}"
  handleAs="json"></core-ajax-dart>

$['ajax']
  ..url="http://$host:9999/services/directory/items/$instanceId"
  ..method = 'POST'
  ..contentType = 'application/json'
  ..body = JSON.encode(rows)
  ..go()
  ;
```

it fails with

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, as as far as I can see the core-ajax-dart method should work as advertised?

CLARIFICATION: I'm already using CORS, and the first HttpRequest.request works fine, just not when trying to POST using core-ajax-dart

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to set CORS headers on the server.

see
- [Client in DART comunicate with server in PHP: access control allow origin headers missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424579)
- [problems with dart-server/angulardart and CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915992)
- [CORS with Dart, how do I get it to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456591)

Comment: Thanks, but I've already done that.  As I said the first HttpRequest.request statement works, but not when using core-ajax-dart.  There's either something wrong with the Polymer Dart version of core-ajax called core-ajax-dart, or I've missed something when trying to use core-ajax-dart.  I'll add the relevant server side code to my question, for clarification purposes.

Comment: I understand. You could look for bugs in the JavaScript core-ajax-dart repo (could be already closed) because Dart version is a bit behind.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think it's related to the JavaScript version though, since this is one of the few core_elements that is a pure Dart port.  Then it could still be related.  I'll look at the JavaScript version and see if I can find a bug relating to this.  So what you're saying is I'm actually using  core-ajax-dart correctly?

Comment: I think to remember that there were such issues but I have no idea how long ago and if they really were similar but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything.